# How do I log out of the Ask Ubuntu website after creating a Stack Exchange account?

Tags: support, login

I can't find a log out button after I created my Ask Ubuntu Stack Exchange account.

Comment: Are you asking how to log out of Ask Ubuntu? Or some other Ubuntu website? (If you use the "Ubuntu One" single-sign-on provider for other Ubuntu-related sites, and you sign into that SSO to access Ask Ubuntu, then you might end up logged in to other sites also.)

Answer (score 16):

After the topbar redesign, the login link has moved to the Stack Exchange icon on the *right* side:

[image: logout link]

You can also just click [this handy link](https://askubuntu.com/users/logout) to log out.

Comment: Thanks, this still works! would it be so hard to provide this link somewhere in the UI?