# I signed in with a less used email and do not have the rep to comment, but there is no log out of ask ubuntu button!

Tags: discussion

I want to log in using another id, as I have too little rep with this one.  There is no ask ubuntu / StackExchange logout button.

Comment: You may also ask the admins to merge your two accounts.

Comment: You'll want to read this: https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/7271/how-do-i-log-out-of-the-ask-ubuntu-website-after-creating-a-stack-exchange-accou

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I log out of the Ask Ubuntu website after creating a Stack Exchange account?](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/7271/how-do-i-log-out-of-the-ask-ubuntu-website-after-creating-a-stack-exchange-accou)